# Passing column name in a random survival forest function in r

Tags: r, string, function, variables, survival

I have an issue and would appreciate some help.

I have a data frame (df) with a variable1 (continuous), Outcome (cat), and time to event (cont). I am doing survival analysis with a random survival forest model.

It works if I do:

```
library(randomForestSRC)

rsf_model <- rfsrc(Surv(Censored_Time,Outcome)~ Variable1,
                   data=df, ntree=1000, mtry=5,min.node.size =3,
                   importance = TRUE)
```

However, when I try to pass the Variable one as a string or any other form it does not work.

```
New_Var <- "Variable1"
rsf_model <- rfsrc(Surv(Censored_Time,Outcome)~ New_Var,
                   data=df, ntree=1000, mtry=5,min.node.size =3,
                   importance = TRUE)
```

Error: Error in finalizeFormula(formulaPrelim, data) the :
formula is misspecified, object Variable1 not found

I tried:

```
New_Var <- df[["Variable1"]]     # also does not work
New_Var <- noquote("Variable1")        # also does not work       
New_Var <- deparse(substitute("Variable1"))  # also does not work
```

I don't want to use `dplyr::(filter = "V1")` and do a `~.` in all variables.

I need to add many variables in multiple steps and different orders so I would love if the formula can evaluate the variable added as a "string" or as any other passable form.

Best regards and thanks in advance!

I expected/want:

```
New_Var <- "Variable1"
rsf_model <- rfsrc(Surv(Censored_Time,Outcome)~ New_Var,
                   data=df, ntree=1000, mtry=5,min.node.size =3,
                   importance = TRUE)
```

to work

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to inform you that I solved. Hope this help someone:

```
New_Var <- "Variable1"
formula_string <- paste("Surv(Censored_Time,Outcome) ~ ", New_Var, sep="")
  formula <- as.formula(formula_string)
  rsf_model <- rfsrc(formula, data = df, ntree = 1000, mtry = 5, min.node.size = 3, importance = TRUE) # This works
```